How to solve this problem when $m$ is an odd number?
$m\in \mathbb{N}^*$ is given. There is an array consists of prime numbers, $p_1,p_2,···$ s.t. $p_n$ is the largest prime factor of $p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}+m$, when $n\geq3$. Prove that the array is bounded.
It is a problem from a book about number theory problems of mathematical olympiad. I have managed to prove that it is right when $m$  is an even number, but I cannot prove it when $m$ is an odd number, but the answer from the book only proves it under the condition of $2\mid m$. After asking some people, I have learnt that there is the limited condition that $m$ is an even number and it is just a wrong printing, but I still wonder whether it is right when $m$ is an odd number, or there is a certain array against it.
When $m$ is an odd number, my progress that might be useful so far is as follow:
First, assume that there were an array satisfied all of the conditions while it is still not bounded. Then I could find endless $p_i$ in it with $p_i\gg m$. For all such $p_i$, if $p_{i+2}>p_{i+1}\geq p_i$, then $p_{i+2}=p_{i+1}+p_{i}+m$.
Here is the solution when $m$ is an even number:
Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $k\cdot((m+3)!)+1\geq max\{p_1,p_2\}$, we only need to prove that $\forall i\in \mathbb{N}^*,p_i\leq k\cdot((m+3)!)+1$.
Assume that when $n\leq r, \forall i\leq n, p_i\leq k\cdot((m+3)!)+1$, then we are going to prove that $p_{r+1} \leq k\cdot((m+3)!)+1$.
When one of $p_r,p_{r-1}$ is $2$, then $p_{r+1}\leq max\{p_r,p_{r-1}\}+2+m\leq k\cdot((m+3)!)+m+3$. If $p_{r+1}$were greater than $k\cdot((m+3)!)+1$, it must be a composite number, which is contradictory to that $p_{r+1}$ is a prime number. Thus $p_{r+1}\leq k\cdot((m+3)!)+1$.
When $p_{r-1},p_r$ are both $2$ or both odd, $p_{r+1}\leq \frac12(p_{r-1}+p_r+m)\leq k\cdot((m+3)!)+\frac m2+1$,then we can prove that $p_{r+1}\leq k\cdot((m+3)!)+1$ in a similar way.
Thus, we can prove the problem by strong mathematical induction.

I suggest:  edit your post to include the proof in the even case.

As to your argument, nothing in the problem statement suggests that the $p_i$ are increasing. Indeed, with $m=1$, $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$, I see the sequence as ${2,3,3,7,11,19,31,17,7,5,13,19,11,31,43,5,7,13,7}$ and of course it's periodic $\overline {13,7}$  after that.  (N.B.  I computed that hastily, by hand, and could well have made an error).

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread A sequence of prime numbers.

@lulu I also noticed that in some particular cases it is easy to find it periodic, but I tried some cases like$p_1=29, p_2=41,m=13.$Then the following sequence goes this way: ${29,41,83,137,233,383,37,433,23,67,103,233,383,37,433,23,67,103,61,59,19,91,41,···}$. In such cases, I can find that you may not be able to simply assert that it’s periodic, but the numbers certainly goes up and down in some way. I believe that it is right when $m$ is an odd number, but I just can’t find evidence. BTW, I’ll post the solution when $m$ is an even number later.
